# Lookup value inside multiline text field

Tags: lookup-column, multiline-text-field

I wonder if it's possible to get lookup values (from another list) inside a multi-line column. I can have these values as a separate lookup column, but I'd like to embed them into text in a multi-line column. I'm using SharePoint as part of O365 - must be one of the most recent versions. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Ruslan, what exactly do you want to achieve by embedding them in multi-line text? A lookup is nothing but a hyperlink column in SharePoint with path to the item from another list and you can add hyperlinks (with path to the desired item in another list) in your multi-line richtext columns anyways.

Comment: Hi harshal, I have a master List with tools / systems / dashboards that should be referenced in the main List. Specifically, the tool names need to be embedded in a process description e.g. "Use #Tool XYZ# to do this. Then use #Tool ABC# to do that". As such, they shouldn't look like hyperlinks, but text-like lookup values. How would such a reference be embedded / looked up in a multiline text column?

Answer (score 0):

OOTB SharePoint doesnt provide such options, you can have  tools / systems / dashboards as lookup columns in your Master List, these columns will be displayed as drop down fields in the Master List new/edit item add page.

In the Master List new/edit item page, you have to add java script functions inside script editor web part. On drop downs (tools / systems / dashboards) item change event, you can get the values selected from the drop downs, concatenate the values and put it into the required Multi Line Text field.